# Using burg to dualboot ubuntu 11.04 and fedora 15 from usb?

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, burg

How can i make grub2 to see my ubuntu from hd and fedora 15 from usb flash,
using burg and natty , cannot find a solution in any forum.
Would appreciate any hints, Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm.... burg or grub2?  if you use burg then replace all the update-grub with update-burg.

keep your fedora 15 usb flash plugged in and mounted when you do a sudo update-grub from your hd ubuntu.  then don't update-grub when your flash drive isn't plugged in.

another way is to just boot from your usb flash using your bios options.  some bios uses F8 to choose which device to boot from.  Different bios use different keys, but once you learn which key to press, you can quickly boot into your usb flash drive when you want to boot from it.

Comment: i installed the live os from my usb to the second hard drive, now i want to use this version in my burg loader. How can i use commands to make this work ?

Comment: when you say use this version, do you mean use it as default?  if you don't want to edit any system files, the best way is still running the sudo update-grub or sudo update-burg command when all bootable drives are mounted.  If for some reason you have master boot records on more than one harddrive it can be a little complicated.  be sure to see if you find relevant solutions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2